# Correct handling of React Hooks for microphone audio

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-audio-api

I'm trying to write a React Hook to handle streaming audio to an AudioContext which is analysed with Meyda.

https://meyda.js.org/

I have managed to get the stream working and am able to pull out the data I want. However, I'm having trouble de-initialising the audio.

If someone can offer me some guidance on setting up this hook correctly I'd be most grateful.

I'm currently receiving the following error when I navigate away from a page using these hooks:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I have attempted to add a cleanup function to the end of my hook, but my attempts often ended with the audio cutting off immediately or any number of other weird bugs.

*Microphone Audio Hook with Meyda Analyser*

```
export const useMeydaAnalyser = () => {

    const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);
    const [features, setFeatures] = useState(null);
    const featuresRef = useRef(features);
    const audioContext = useRef(new AudioContext());

    const getMedia = async() => {
        try {
            return await navigator
                .mediaDevices
                .getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
        }
    };

    useEffect(
        () => {
            const audio = audioContext.current;
            let unmounted = false;
            if(!running) {
                getMedia().then(stream => {
                    if (unmounted) return;
                    setRunning(true);
                    const source = audio.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                    const analyser = Meyda.createMeydaAnalyzer({
                        audioContext: audio,
                        source: source,
                        bufferSize: 1024,
                        featureExtractors: [
                            'amplitudeSpectrum',
                            'mfcc',
                            'rms',
                        ],
                        callback: nextFeatures => {
                            if(!isEqual(featuresRef.current, nextFeatures)) {
                                setFeatures(nextFeatures);
                            }
                        },
                    });
                    analyser.start();
                });
            }
            return () => {
                unmounted = true;
            }
        },
        [running, audioContext],
    );

    useEffect(
        () => {
            featuresRef.current = features;
        },
        [features],
    );

    return features;
};
```

*Audio View*

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { useMeydaAnalyser } from '../hooks/use-meyda-audio';

const AudioViewDemo = () => {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const features = useMeydaAnalyser(audioContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        // Todo: Handle Audio features
        console.log(features);
        // setAudioData(features);
    }, [features]);

    return (
        <div>
            RMS: {features && features.rms}
        </div>
    );
};

export default AudioViewDemo;
```

Comment: The question previously contained this, I've split it up for clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320960/correct-handling-of-react-hooks-for-streaming-video-camera-to-html-video-element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error should be caused by not closing `AudioContext`. You need to close `AudioContext` in the cleanup functions.

Note that before using `AudioContext`, determine if the state is off, because `getMedia` is asynchronous, so if the component is unloaded soon after loading, `AudioContext` is turned off when it is used.

[image: Edit epic-mayer-23u56]

```js
const getMedia = async () => {
  try {
    return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: false,
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err)
  }
}

const useMeydaAnalyser = () => {
  const [analyser, setAnalyser] = useState(null)
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false)
  const [features, setFeatures] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext()

    let newAnalyser
    getMedia().then(stream => {
      if (audioContext.state === 'closed') {
        return
      }
      const source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
      newAnalyser = Meyda.createMeydaAnalyzer({
        audioContext: audioContext,
        source: source,
        bufferSize: 1024,
        featureExtractors: ['amplitudeSpectrum', 'mfcc', 'rms'],
        callback: features => {
          console.log(features)
          setFeatures(features)
        },
      })
      setAnalyser(newAnalyser)
    })
    return () => {
      if (newAnalyser) {
        newAnalyser.stop()
      }
      if (audioContext) {
        audioContext.close()
      }
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (analyser) {
      if (running) {
        analyser.start()
      } else {
        analyser.stop()
      }
    }
  }, [running, analyser])

  return [running, setRunning, features]
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try it out now.

Comment: Works a treat thank you very much. I imagine in principle a similar pattern will work for the video stream. I'll if I can work it out.

Comment: I think I'll move the bit's related to the video element to a new question. This seems to solve the Audio handling part of it nicely.

Comment: I am not quite sure what trouble you have encountered on the video stream. Can you elaborate?

In addition, I also have a demo about video streaming on the same CodeSandbox. You can check it out. Since I don't have a camera installed here, I use the video preview of the screen preview.

Comment: I will do, I haven't had time to split it up. Once I have I'll mark this as correct and add the link to the new question here

Comment: I have moved the video portion of the question out to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57320960/correct-handling-of-react-hooks-for-streaming-video-camera-to-html-video-element. I have managed to improve the handling based on this answer. Thanks again for taking the time to look over this, has been really useful.